Building an iOS App - Not allowed to save JSON file using Swift while testing on real device, but on simulator it works
I am trying to make an iOS app, and I have to save a JSON file but I get this error:
Landmarks/ModelData.swift:45: Fatal error: Couldn't write to /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/.../Landmarks.app/landmarkData.json:
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save the file “landmarkData.json” in the folder “Landmarks”."
However, this only happens while testing the app on my iPhone 11, while running the app on the simulator, it works as expected.
This is the save function I'm using:
func save(_ landmarks: [Landmark]) {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    
    do {
        let data = try encoder.encode(landmarks)
        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("landmarkData.json")
        guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "landmarkData.json", withExtension: nil)
        else {
            fatalError("Couldn't find landmarkData.json in main bundle.")
        }
        
        do {
            try data.write(to: file)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Couldn't write to \(file.path):\n\(error)")
        }
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't encode landmarks as JSON:\n\(error)")
    }
}

I think I have to save the file in another folder, such as the documents one, but I'm not sure how I'd do that.
I tried this:
import Foundation

@Observable
class ModelData {
    init() {
        copyFileFromBundleToDocumentsFolder(sourceFile: "landmarkData.json")
        landmarks = load("landmarkData.json")
    }
    
    var landmarks: [Landmark] = []
}

func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
    let data: Data
    
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(filename)
    
    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in Documents directory:\n\(error)")
    }
    
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
    }
}

func save(_ landmarks: [Landmark]) {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    
    do {
        let data = try encoder.encode(landmarks)
        
        let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("landmarkData.json")
        
        do {
            try data.write(to: fileURL)
            print("Successfully wrote data to \(fileURL.path)")
        } catch {
            fatalError("Couldn't write to \(fileURL.path):\n\(error)")
        }
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't encode landmarks as JSON:\n\(error)")
    }
}

func copyFileFromBundleToDocumentsFolder(sourceFile: String) {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentsURL = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let destinationURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(sourceFile)
    
    if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: destinationURL.path) {
        if let sourceURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: sourceFile, withExtension: nil) {
            do {
                try fileManager.copyItem(at: sourceURL, to: destinationURL)
                print("\(sourceFile) copied to Documents directory.")
            } catch {
                print("Error copying file: \(error)")
            }
        } else {
            print("Source file not found in bundle.")
        }
    }
}


But it neither returned any error, but also couldn't read from / write to the file, so I'm assuming it's not using the correct path.
Thanks in advance!

You say
guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "landmarkData.json", withExtension: nil) and then you have try data.write(to: file) - you are trying to write data to the application bundle. You can do this on the simulator because the file sandbox is not enforced, but in a real device the bundle is read-only.
Regardless, this isn't what you actually wanted to do. You want to save it to the fileURL location: try write(to: fileURL)

Hello, sorry, but I’m not sure I get the second part of your answer. Isn’t that what I did in the second code I provided: data.write(to: fileURL)? As I said, the code can neither load the file or save it, probably because it doesn’t exist, so I’m assuming it doesn’t get correctly moved to the Documents Directory.

Your question is unclear. You provided one block of code and an error message that it produces. I have shown the error in that block of code.  You say that your second block of code doesn't produce any errors but it can't read or write from the file. If it doesn't produce any errors, how do you know that it can't read or write the file. Have you set breakpoints and stepped through the code with the debugger to see what it is doing?
